# Extract from Data Extension using Webservice

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a data extension ("CustomerResponse") in Marketing Cloud.
We want to extract data extension from this data extension and populate a custom object ("Customer_Response__c") in our Salesforce Sales Cloud.
Is there a REST Webservice available in Marketing Cloud for querying data from a data extension ?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [this route](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc-custom_object_data?meta=Summary&q=customobjectdata):

`{{hostEndpoint}}data/v1/customobjectdata/key/{{DEKey}}/rowset`

I'd also suggest checking out the official [SFMC Postman collection](https://www.postman.com/salesforce-developers/workspace/salesforce-developers/collection/14448118-2835a976-010c-4548-92f8-f42c0382758e).  It's more helpful than the official documentation, IMO.